# Требуется конкретный совет где изучать

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Я начинающий PHP разработчик,меня очень интересует данный язык, хочу заниматься в ближайшее время написанием скриптов и логики для сайтов. Но я начал свой путь с нуля, подскажите пожалуйста помимо изучения самого языка, где и могу черпать информацию, с каких определенных ресурсов касательно основ программирования. Например что такое хостинг,какие бывают методы отправки форм, как устроена всемирная паутина Интернет. Такие базовые вещи который должен знать каждый программист. Мне очень важен любой ответ, этот вопрос это крик, потому что уже на протяжении полугода пытаюсь изучать все,но получается все в кривь и в кось...Всем буду благодарен,прошу отнестись с пониманием,спасибо

Comment: Для начала Вам надо определиться, что именно вы планируете, уж слишком большой разброс информации. Начните со структурирования своего обучения. https://habr.com/ru/post/249983/

Comment: https://itvdn.com/ru/specialities/php-developer

Answer (score 1):

Просто в качестве идеи: мне, в своё время, в изучении помогла необходимость решать конкретные задачи. Типа, ставите перед собой конкретную задачу - разместить сайт в Интернете. Забиваете пока на качество этого сайта и тд, а просто ищете информацию, как разместить бесплатно сайт в сети, т.е. информацию про бесплатные хостинги.

И так далее

Comment: спасибо за идею)

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте по возможности и по нужности. Например вам нужно разметить сайт, вы вычитываете по разным ресурсам как разместить сайт в интернете. Например для начала, подойдет простой хостинг https://www.zzz.com.ua/ru. Он бесплатен и легок в установлении. Чтобы изучить отдельные методы, изучайте методы, которые вам понадобятся. Никогда не учите все подряд, так как вы забиваете себе мозг, их там большое множество. Про то, что связано с програмирование не тесно, например, так как вы сказали как устроена всемирная паутина Интернет, вы можете почитать на Википедии, или других ресурсов. Так же не советую учить только PHP. PHP в единственном екземпляре в вашем инструментарии, так же, как у вас есть только молоток, а вам дали закрутить шуруп. Вы то шуруп прибьете, но не очень качественно. Если вы хотите пойти только в бекенд, советую изучать еще JavaScript и MySQL. Я учусь самостоятельно, но если у вас есть возможность пойти на бесплатные курсы по програмированию, не упустите возможности. Вы сможете познакомится с новыми людьми, которые с радостью помогут вам в вашем выборе и в учении, а так же вы можете на них изучить что то новое для вас. Не берите платные курсы, они того не стоят. Вам пообещают, что из вас сделают супер програмиста, но на самом деле ето не так, так что денег на них тратить не стоит. Так как я учусь самостоятельно, я прорываю весь интернет в поисках всего, чего мне интересно. Так же может вам будет интересно и познавательно к каждому проекту делать "Курсовые". Так вы сможете изучить тему своего проекта глубже, ищя информацию на просторах Интернета. Я хочу быть "фулстаком", если ето можна так описать, в области Веб, так что я изучаю и бекенд и фронтенд, то есть HTML, PHP, JavaScript, CSS, MySQL, впринципе, етот набор пригодится всегда в работе Веб разработчика, если можно сказать, то ето полностью самостоятельный набор, с которым вы сможете построить вашу программу как вам захочется. А вообще, просто понемногу изучайте разные сферы Веб програмирования, со временем вы постигните все, что вам будет нужно

Comment: спасибо за ответ